# Custom Drush command to export old Drupal project settings (.yml files) to a new project

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drush

The project is about to make a custom Drush command to export old Drupal project settings (.yml files) to a new project, my question is how to make this.

Comment: Did you do some research on this? There are some tutorials available on net. I.e. https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-drush-commands

Comment: Yes, but how can I run it ?

Comment: Or that copies the project settings